# Numba vs Cython loop optimization

Tags: python, cython, numba

Consider the following four functions (`python`, `numba`, `cython` and `smart`), which calculate identical responses when given the same integer inputs

```
def python(n):
    total = 0
    for m in range(1,n+1):
        total += m
    return total

from numba import jit
numba = jit(python)

cpdef int cython(int n):
    cdef int total = 0
    cdef int m
    for m in range(1, n+1):
        total += m
    return total

def smart(n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2
```

Timing their execution I was somewhat surprised to discover that

1. `numba`'s run-time is independent of `n` (while `cython`'s is linear in `n`)
2. `numba` is slower than `smart`

This immediately raises two questions:

1. Why is Numba, but not Cython, able to turn it into a constant-time algorithm?
2. Given that Numba *does* manage to turn it into a contstant-time algorithm, why is it slower than the pure Python constant-time function `smart`?

As I am no assembler maven, looking at the generated code doesn't really give me much of a clue, beyond that the intermediate LLVM code generated by Numba still appears (I might have misunderstood, though) to contain a loop ... and I get hopelessly lost in the x64 that is eventually generated from that. (Unless someone asks, I won't post the generated codes, as they are rather long.)

I am running this on a x64 Linux, in a Jupyter notebook, so I suspect that Cython is using the GCC 4.4.7 which was used to compile Python; and llvmlite 0.20.0, which would imply LLVM 4.0.x.

## Edit:

I have also timed

```
smart_numba = jit(smart)
```

and

```
cpdef int smart_cython(int n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2
```

`smart_numba` and `numba` give identical timings, which are 25% **slower** than `smart` (pure-Python) and 175% slower than `smart_cython`.

Does this indicate that Cython does a very good job of efficiently crossing the Python/low-level boundary, while Numba does a poor job? Or is there something else to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. This appears to be a LLVM vs GCC thing - see example in compiler explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/g/8oWJ2u), which is less noisy than what numba spits out.  I get a bit lost in the assembly, but fairly clear that the GCC output has a loop (the `jge` to `.L6`) and the clang output does not.  See also [this issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46186) on the GCC bugtracker.
2. On my machine (Windows x64) `numba` is not significantly slower than `smart`, only about 9 ns.  This overhead appears to be due to the type dispatch mechanism of numba - if you elide it by picking a specific overload, the numba version is faster than the python one

Here are my timings

```
In [73]: %timeit numba_sum(10000)
182 ns ± 1.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [74]: %timeit smart(10000)
171 ns ± 2.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

# pick out int64 overload
i64_numba_sum = numba_sum.get_overload((numba.int64,))

In [75]: %timeit i64_numba_sum(10000)
94 ns ± 1.41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes, godbolt makes absence/presence of the loop pretty clear. But I'm confused by the use of registers starting with `e`, which I understand to be 32 bit. Numba definitely inferred `int64`. If I change the `int` to `long int` the clang output becomes very long and complicated, beyond my ability to decipher. It's interesting that on your machine `numba` is faster than `smart`: on mine it's 25% **slower**. Numba also slows down `smart` to match the speed of `numba` (which isn't surprising once you've seen that `numba` is slower than `smart`).

Comment: Sorry misspoke, I meant not significantly _slower_.  See edit, it seems the type dispatch is actually what creates the overhead in the numba version.